# JSF Navigation outcome constants

Tags: jsf-2, constants

I wonder if i can replace "success" with a Constants value from a JSF library.

Backing Bean Method:

```
@Override
public String save() {
    LOG.info("Called");
    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, you'll find Omnifaces' [`<o:importConstants />`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants) so useful (that's what I use in my own projects). That way you can import your constants file in your JSF page (I use my master page template for that).

```
<o:importConstants
    type="com.mycompany.NavigationResults" />
```

This way you can access your NavigationResults values both from Java code and JSF tags (EL scope).

```
public abstract class NavigationResults {
    public static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String HOME = "home";
}
```

Use it in your managed beans:

```
public String save() {
    LOG.info("Called");
    return NavigationResults.SUCCESS;
}
```

In your buttons or links:

```
<h:button value="Go home" outcome="#{NavigationResults.HOME}" />
```